# HTML/CSS centered formatting

Tags: html, css, formatting, centering

Im just messing around with Ruby on Rails and HTML. This question isn't about RoR, but HTML and CSS. When I center my body, I get this:
[Help http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/2203/help.tif](http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/2203/help.tif)

How can i get the bullets to be centered next to the text as well?

Also, how can I get the while border collapse so its closer to the text?

Here is my code:

My app layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults -%>
        <title><%= page_title.capitalize -%></title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'main' %>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="body" style="margin:0 auto; width:600px;">
            <%= yield -%>
            <%= render :partial => "layouts/footer" -%>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

My Page, which has the list:

```
<h1 id="welcome_sign">Welcome!</h1>
<h3 id= "sitemap">Site Map </h3>

<ul>
    <li><%= link_to "Animals", "/animals"%></li>
        <ol><li><%= link_to "Hello", "/animals/hello"%></li></ol>
    <li><%= link_to "Machines", "/machines"%></li>
    <ol>
        <li><%= link_to "Products", "/machines/products" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Report", "/machines/report" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Robot", "/machines/robot" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Show", "/machines/show" %></li>
    </ol>
</ul>
```

And finally, my CSS:

```
#footer {
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sitemap {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 2.0em;
    padding: 10px;

}

#welcome_sign {
    padding: 10px;
 }

body {
    background-color: #CDEAFF;

}

#body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 5px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #999;
    border-right: 5px solid #999;
    border-left: 5px solid #999;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The screenshot is nice. The actual HTML would be nicer. We're coders, we need to see code.

Comment: Since you admit this has nothing to do with Ruby on Rails, I removed the `ror` tag.

Comment: Code is now there. BTW I added the ROR tag back because now it does deal with ruby on rails :D

Comment: Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that when you say you want the list centered, what you actually want is to center the *bounding box* around the list.  Using the table display mode on it and setting auto margins works for everything except for IE.  For the sake of IE, you instead have to set a width on the list.

Another thing that should be fixed is the way that you're building the list.  The only elements that should appear inside of an ul element are li elements.  In other words, the ol's should appear inside of the li's.

Here it is all put together:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      h1, h3 { text-align: center; }
      ul { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 100px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="welcome_sign">Welcome!</h1>
    <h3 id="sitemap">Site Map</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
          Animals
          <ol>
            <li>Hello</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
          Machines
          <ol>
            <li>Products</li>
            <li>Report</li>
            <li>Robot</li>
            <li>Show</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
    </ul>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The better practice is to center the text one element at a time, rather than at the body level.

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:800px;">
<h4 style="text-align:center">Welcome</h4>
<ul>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Not only does this give you far better control of your layout, it will also allow you to ONLY center things that you want to.

---

After seeing your code below, remove the text-align: center; in the #body tag, this should help alleviate the list icons sticking to the left.

Comment: Hmm that KIND of works... The problem now is that all the text is on the right-inside of the white box. i want ALL the text to be centered. Any ideas?

Comment: and i also need the "Site Map" to be directly UNDER the "Welcome"

Comment: Putting it directly under the welcome is just a matter of setting the line-height on the h4 element, as well as the padding/margin.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to set the text-indent property, and probably adjust the margins and padding as well.

From the looks of your screenshot though, you're missing some fundamental understanding of HTML. You would have to be doing something wacky to display the bullets like that.

Post the code and I can give a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are centring the list elements (text) but not the list itself. If you would inspect the elements with e.g. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) then you would see the real size of each element. And then you will realize why it is centred like this.

I recommend you to read this [tutorial about lists](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the list in a container div, and using the margin-left/right: auto trick. I'd avoid centering a list, since it ruins the organization of the content.

```
<div style="width: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
[your list here]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an fyi... you can actually style the  element. Personally, I'd narrow that down and center it. You also want to avoid doing `text-align: center` on *all* elements; i.e, you probably want something like the following...

```
<style type="text/css">
    html { text-align: center; }
    body { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
    li { text-align: left; }
</style>
```

Comment: thats good, but the thing is the list is on the left. I need the whole list, including the dots and numbers to be in the center